# passing a list of columns into a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

ok, here's my situation, I have a list of variables I want to pass into a stored procedure. each variable represents a column in a database(dbImage) and are boolean.

```
--Columnslist contains Var1, Var2, Var3
@ColumnsList varchar(Max)
```

I want to pass them into the select statement and var1,var2, and var3 as true

```
SELECT @ColumnsList from dtImage WHERE @ColumnsList = True
```

I know it may be confusing, I know what I want to do. I just have a really hard time explaining what I want to do.

Comment: I'm not sure but it sounds like you might want to look into dynamic sql... Are you trying to have a variable list of column name selected?

Comment: What would `WHERE @ColumnsList = True` even mean?

Comment: @ColumnsList = "var1,var2,var3" what I want is to compare each var in @ColumnsList where each var = true.  That's what I mean by that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean that suppose you have a table as follows

```
CREATE TABLE bits
(
id INT PRIMARY KEY,
col1 BIT,
col2 BIT,
col3 BIT,
col4 BIT
)
```

Populated as follows

```
INSERT INTO bits 
VALUES (1,0,0,0,0), 
       (2,1,1,1,1),
       (3,1,1,0,0)
```

And you pass in the string

```
DECLARE @ColumnsList VARCHAR(MAX) = 'col1,col2,col3'
```

You want to get back row 2 because that's the only one where the value for all these columns is `1`?

If so probably dynamic SQL or some sort of bitwise query will be the most sensible solution. In the meantime here's a solution without either.

```
SELECT id
FROM   bits UNPIVOT(val FOR col IN (col1, col2, col3, col4)) unpvt
       JOIN (SELECT col
             FROM   (SELECT CAST('<c>' + REPLACE(@ColumnsList, ',', '</c><c>') + '</c>' AS XML) AS x) x
                    CROSS APPLY (SELECT t.split.value('.', 'sysname') AS col
                                 FROM   x.nodes('/c') t(split)) ca) cols
         ON cols.col = unpvt.col
GROUP  BY id
HAVING COUNT(CASE
               WHEN val = 0 THEN 1
             END) = 0
```

Comment: ya seems dynamic sql is the way to go, and I can pull up the data that way but not getting how to write a where statement based on it

Comment: @Joel - But have I understood the requirement correctly in the first place? Also if you decide to generate the query dynamically you're probably much better off doing it in your application than splitting the string apart and rejoining it in TSQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dynamic sql statement and execute it with `sp_ExecuteSql`
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx